# How do I stop my inner divs floating on top of each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a flip card but all the divs inside the card seem to be floating on top of each other. I want the divs to be next to each other.

I have looked at a lot of questions but can't seem to find the answer. I have tried a variety of display:inline; position:relative; float:left; clear:both; but I can't seem to get the divs next to each other.

Can anybody make it so the inner divs (".putmenextTo") are next to each other?

```css
.flipcardHold {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .flipcardFront {
  background: red;
}

.card .flipcardBack {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.putmenextTo {
  /*things already tried
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<button id="flipbutton">flip the card</button>
<div class="flipcardHold">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="flipcardFront">
      <!--I want the below divs to be next to each other -->
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv1" class="putmenextTo">Front First div</div>
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv2" class="putmenextTo">Front Second div</div>
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv3" class="putmenextTo">Front Third div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flipcardBack">
      <!--I want the below divs to be next to each other -->
      <div id="Backinnerdiv1" class="putmenextTo">Back First div</div>
      <div id="Backinnerdiv2" class="putmenextTo">Back Second div</div>
      <div id="Backinnerdiv3" class="putmenextTo">Back Third div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  $("#flipbutton").click(function() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `float:left`, specific `width` on inner div and change parent `width:300px` from `width:100px` for next to each other, and change `position:absolute` to `relative`

```css
.flipcardHold {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div.flipcardFront,.card div.flipcardBack{
  width:100%;
}

.card div {
  border-radius: 15px;
  float:left;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;/*changed*/
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .flipcardFront {
  background: red;
}

.card .flipcardBack {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.putmenextTo {
  /*things already tried
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<button id="flipbutton">flip the card</button>
<div class="flipcardHold">
  <div class="card ss">
    <div class="flipcardFront">
      <!--I want the below divs to be next to each other -->
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv1" class="putmenextTo">Front First div</div>
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv2" class="putmenextTo">Front Second div</div>
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv3" class="putmenextTo">Front Third div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flipcardBack">
      <!--I want the below divs to be next to each other -->
      <div id="Backinnerdiv1" class="putmenextTo">Back First div</div>
      <div id="Backinnerdiv2" class="putmenextTo">Back Second div</div>
      <div id="Backinnerdiv3" class="putmenextTo">Back Third div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  $("#flipbutton").click(function() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have make some changes

```css
.flipcardHold {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;/*changed*/
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
  height: auto;/*changed*/
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;/*changed*/
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .flipcardFront {
  background: red;
}

.card .flipcardBack {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;/*new*/
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.putmenextTo {
  /*things already tried
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<button id="flipbutton">flip the card</button>
<div class="flipcardHold">
  <div class="card ss">
    <div class="flipcardFront">
      <!--I want the below divs to be next to each other -->
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv1" class="putmenextTo">Front First div</div>
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv2" class="putmenextTo">Front Second div</div>
      <div id="Frontinnerdiv3" class="putmenextTo">Front Third div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flipcardBack">
      <!--I want the below divs to be next to each other -->
      <div id="Backinnerdiv1" class="putmenextTo">Back First div</div>
      <div id="Backinnerdiv2" class="putmenextTo">Back Second div</div>
      <div id="Backinnerdiv3" class="putmenextTo">Back Third div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  $("#flipbutton").click(function() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works good to stop the divs on top of each other. Do you know how I can get the divs to float next to each other though? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Flexbox instead.

By default, flexbox is displaying childs divs in rows (you got more options if you wanna space them, etc...)

Try adding the following code on FlipcardBack & FlipcardFront.

```css
.card .flipcardFront {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;  

  background: red;
}

.card .flipcardBack {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;  

  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```